texcount error with biblatex \DeclareCiteCommand
I stumbled onto the following texcount error when trying to work with a large latex document:
!!! Encountered } without corresponding {. !!!

!!! Reached end of file while waiting for }. !!!

I tracked it down to use of \DeclareCiteCommand from biblatex. Passing the following snippet to the texcount web interface reproduces the error:
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}{...}{...}{...}{...}

I saw from the docs that I can decorate the code with %TC:ignore and %TC:endignore but was wondering whether this should be considered a bug in texcount that I should report. Of course, if I missed something, I would be happy to change things on the latex part.

The macro \DeclareCiteCommand is not supported, and so is handled using the default handling rules; and this is one of the cases where the default handling rule fails badly. As such, it is not a bug, and you can safely use %TC:ignore and %TC:endignore to exclude it.
TeXcount does not support all macros: in particular, a lot of macros from packages are not supported. For unsupported macros, it has default handling rules which have been made to handle most cases acceptably well if not perfectly, and only rarely screw things up badly.
The reason it fails in this case is that the default rule is to process macro arguments using the same word counting rule as outside the macro. That means TeXcount tries to analyse {\cite} as a block of LaTeX code. Since the \cite macro is supported and requires an argument, TeXcount tries to parse the argument only to find a }. Basically, it tries to parse the } following \cite as an argument, and in the context of parsing an argument does not expect a } not preceded by a {, hence the error message.
An alternative to using %TC:ignore is to add a handling rule for the \DeclareCiteCommand macro, specifying the arguments and how each of them is to be parsed. This can be done by adding the following line to the document somewhere at the top, before the macro is being used:
%TC:macro \DeclareCiteCommand [xxx,xx,xx,xx,xx]

This adds a handling rule that \DeclareCiteCommand takes 5 argument, of which the first should be parsed using the Stronger exclude rule denoted xxx, the remaining using the xx strong exclude rule. If this rule still fails on some of the arguments, it may be necessary to replace xx with xxx.
The different parsing rules are explained in the TeXcount online documentation. Basically, ignore will fully parse the code without counting the words, while the xx strong exclude rule allows for unbalanced \begin or \end, both of which will produce an error if trying to parse {\cite}. The xxx stronger exclude rule treats macros merely as tokens without processing them as macros, which allows \cite to be to be ignore without try to parse its argument. The xall exclude all rule is not applicable to macros, but used by %TC:ignore and some special environments like verbatim.
